# removing nodes from xml incomplete, needs several runs

Tags: xml, dom

I have a very strange bug I am trying to figure out. I load in an xml, find a specific node, then delete it, then save the file. But when I run it, it only catches SOME of those nodes on the first run, then some more on the second and third runs until it finally finishes. There is no reason I can figure why this is happening. Here is my code:

```
foreach(glob("*.xml") as $filename) {
$domsrc = file_get_contents($filename, FILE_TEXT);
$MYdom = new DomDocument();
$MYdom->loadXML($domsrc);

foreach ($MYdom->getElementsByTagName('URL') as $virttour) {
    if($virttour->getAttribute('Type') == 'Virtual Tour') {
$virttour->parentNode->removeChild($virttour); 
   }
}
$MYdom->save($filename);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea what was causing this, but I reworked the code in a different way, and now it correctly catches everything in one run:

```
foreach(glob("*.xml") as $filename) {
$domsrc = file_get_contents($filename, FILE_TEXT);
$MYdom = new DomDocument();
$MYdom->loadXML($domsrc);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($MYdom);
$nodeList = $xpath->query('//URL[@Type="Virtual Tour"]');

foreach ($nodeList as $node){
if ($nodeList->length>0) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}
$MYdom->save($filename);
```

Again, NO IDEA why it wasn't working with the other code in one go, but hopefully this will help someone else who may run across something like this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your first bit of code is not working is because the node list or the list created by $MYdom->getElementsByTagName('URL') is dynamic. This means that when you remove the element it changes the length of the nodes and their position. The foreach statement ends up skipping elements because their positions have changed. The best way of accomplishing your original statement is using a for statement that takes this into account:

```
$nodes = $MYdom->getElementsByTagName('URL')

for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
                  $node = $nodes->item($i);
                  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
                  $i--;
                }
```

Or a while statement:

```
while($nodes->length) {
                  $node = $FlavorNodes->item(0);
                  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
                }
```